# Navicat for MySQL: Can I export each result set (multiple) from one query into individual CSV files?

Tags: mysql, navicat, database-management

[Query with multiple results in Navicat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mvG5.png)

I am running multiple SELECT statements in one query using Navicat, receiving multiple Result sets. All results are separated into 'Result 1', 'Result 2', 'Result 3', etc. When I export the current result however, all result sets are appended into a singular CSV or Excel file.

Is there a way to export each result set into its own CSV/Excel file? I'd also be satisfied with one Excel file with multiple sheets.

I've tried the different export options using the export wizard, but the results just seem to be unioned together.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.